# [spring][jsp] Problem with css file

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have problem with .css file on my JSP page.

My page looks like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

...
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...

<body>

<div id="header">....
```

When I deploy my application on JBoss5.1 a get a warn message:

WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/appTest1-web/test.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appTest1'

Anybody know why?

**ADDED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>appTest1</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appTest1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appTest1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the base URL that you're using to call this page: /appTest1 by chance?

I assume you simply have placed this page/controller under /appTest1 and thus when it looks for any resource on the page (e.g. your css, any image, js's, etc) it is looking under "/appTest1/your_resource"

Perhaps the class that contains your controller has something like @RequestMapping("appTest1")? or perhaps that's a JBoss artifact (if so, I'm not a JBoss guy, so can't suggest ideas there).

In any case, your CSS file should probably be referenced appropriately with either "../test.css", or the static reference, such as: "/static/css/test.css", I choose the latter.

Incidentally, in spring I configured a static directory for non-dynamic content with:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/public/"/>
```

Large scale websites also consider putting static content under a separate domain such as static.mydomain.com or mycontentdomain.net to avoid having cookies passed along with static content.

Hope all that helps you get yourself pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I added my web.xml to the question

Comment: Ok, I added <mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/public/"/> and I was change <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> to <link href="public/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">The exception does not appear, but I do not see the jsp can not see the style: (

Comment: Can you open the css file in your browser? If yes, try to use the absolute path from your browsers address bar in the href element of the link.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more, how you have solved the problem? where you placed the "public" folder, under the WEB-INF directory? I have the same problem, and I can't browse the css file from the address bar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your DispatcherServlet is trying to process the test.css. Check your web.xml to see if * or .css requests are directed to your DispatcherServlet. You should look for something like below. Make sure to limit the url-pattern to the extensions you want to be directed to the dispatcher servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>dispatcher</servlet>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you somewhere else in xml make mistake, but in more advanced redirection you can use UrlRewrite filter http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/